# Can I develop a .NET application in Windows and deploy versions for Linux and Mac?

Tags: .net, deployment, mono, cross-platform, monodevelop

Is this possible with, e.g., MonoDevelop perhaps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you don't even need to use MonoDevelop, the DLLs/EXEs created by Visual Studio and Microsoft's C# compiler are (for the most part) 100% compatible with Mono.

You have to avoid features and libraries that Mono doesn't support, of course, but that list is getting smaller every day...

Comment: Haha, I like that: "for the most part 100%"... so what percent of 100%? ;) In all seriousness, though, I did not realize you could straight-up run an EXE on Mono! That is definitely good to know.

Comment: @Dan, heh, yeah I added that qualification later so now it doesn't quite make sense... you get the drift anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

YES, some possibilities:

if your .NET minded:
You can use visual studio and install mono on windows. There are tools you can than test in it if it works for linux too (dont use unsupported libraries in code ect).

You can use monodevelop too as IDE to program on mono framework with .NET languages. Some positive of mondevelop is too it can be used on linux.